# Copy files inside a folder iteratively - Bash

Tags: bash, copy

I want to copy all the files inside `dmir.bedpostX` folder, to a different location, keeping the structure.

```
   Bedpost_Controls

   └───C01
   │   └─── dmri.bedpostX
   │       └─── *files*
   └───C02
   │   └─── dmri.bedpostX
   │       └─── *files* 
   └───C03
   │   └─── dmri.bedpostX
   │       └─── *files*


   Bedpost_Patients

   └───H01
   │   └─── dmri.bedpostX
   │       └─── *files*
   │
```

So, in my new directory, I would have the folder distribution just seen above. The thing is, inside `C01, C02` folder etc, there are other files I don´t  want to copy.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/media/HD_2/mark/Analysis"
for group in Controls Patients; do 
    cd "$DIR/Bedpost_${group}" || exit
    for folder in *; do
        orig="$folder/dmri.bedpostX"
        dest="/media/HD_2/roy/Analysis/Bedpost_${group}/$orig"; 
        mkdir -p $dest
        cp "$orig/*" "$dest/"
    done;
done;
```

This copies the directories, but doesn´t recognize the glob:

`cp: cannot stat '/H47_1/dmri.bedpostX/*': No such file or directory`

I tried to glob both with `"` and without.

Edit: I tried copying just one file, with the command `cp "$orig/nodif_brain_mask.nii.gz" "$dest/"`, and this prompted the error:

```
cp: cannot stat '/C01_1/dmri.bedpostX/nodif_brain_mask.nii.gz': No such file or directory
```

How is this? The same script has worked previously with different files.

Comment: To maintain the glob, use `"$orig/"*`rather than `"$orig/*"`. But I agree with the answer below: using `rsync` would be a much better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not restricted to bash I would look at rsync, you can exclude certain files using pattern matching [https://www.howtogeek.com/168009/how-to-exclude-files-from-rsync/].

as for your Bash script issue,

orig="$folder/dmri.bedpostX" - $folder is an absolute path (starts with / )
did you mean to prefix it with $DIR/ ?